# Why controls goes out of div with class thumbnail?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap for design web for and have created controls inside div with class thumbnail but that controls going out of that div. Here is [link to code](https://fiddle.jshell.net/760nvam4/)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Do you want all the content in the first box ?

Comment: @Nikhilesh, I want to put all control for login in first box provided when size minimize or maximize that control should be there and not to let them to go outside..

Comment: You can use media queries and reduce the size of the textbox and labels for smaller screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `thumbnail` height to `Auto`, also you can set the `min-height` for empty `thumbnail` divs, like this:

```
.thumbnail {
    height:auto !important;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

---

***Edit #1:***

Try removing `col-xs-6 col-md-6` classes and float your button to ***right*** *( also if you want add another button you can flaot it to **left** )*, like this:

```
#btnsubmit{
      float:right;
}
```

[***Updated Fiddle #2***](https://fiddle.jshell.net/3njf6y6s/)

[***Updated Fiddle #3***](https://fiddle.jshell.net/9eb9exbL/) *(using overflow:hidden;)*

Comment: still button controls goes outside even though by setting width to auto and min-width to 150px..

Comment: should I set min-width and min-height to all parent control to not to let them minimize less than controls width or are there any way to  handle control width also?

Comment: @Kaishu no.. min-width and min-height you can add them for empty divs if you want (it's optional)

Comment: I have tried code you have updated currently but when I completely minimize window, the thumbnails are completely getting minimized but label text and input controls goes outside.

Comment: @Kaishu When you completely minimize window i suggest add _overflow:hidden;_ to _thumbnail class_ in this case like [this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/9eb9exbL/), it's just another suggestion. i hope it helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109682/discussion-between-kaishu-and-shady-alset).